# How to understand Trace from dmesg?

Tags: kernel, dmesg, trace

I'm learning linux kernel debugging and dmesg is the tool that output kernel debug log:

```
...
[    2.988000] Trace:
[    2.988000] [<ffffffff80942810>] __warn+0x160/0x190
[    2.988000] [<ffffffff8111ae9c>] dwc3_probe+0xc1c/0x1e60
[    2.988000] [<ffffffff8111ae9c>] dwc3_probe+0xc1c/0x1e60
[    2.988000] [<ffffffff80fe4434>] platform_drv_probe+0x34/0x90
...
```

- Question 1: IIUC, `__warn` is kernel function, but what's the meaning of `0x160/0x190`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16742918/2072269):

> ```
> [10991.880408] EIP: 0060:[<c06969d4>] EFLAGS: 00210246 CPU: 0
> [10991.880411] EIP is at iret_exc+0x7d0/0xa59
> ```
>
> That gives you the faulting instruction pointer, both directly and in symbol+offset form. The part after the slash is the size of the function.

Assuming a similar format, `ffffffff80942810` is the address, `__warn` is the symbol, `0x160` is the offset from that symbol, and `0x190` is the size of the `__warn` function.